# Can a user modify a PHP session?

Tags: php

Page1.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_POST['password'] == "testpass")
    $_SESSION['authenticated'] = true;
?>
```

Page2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['authenticated']) && $_SESSION['authenticated'] == true) {
    echo "Super secret stuff!";
}
?>
```

Can a user get in without the super secure password?

Comment: A user cannot modify PHP sessions on the server. They can only forge a legitimate cookie and masquerade as a logged-in user - but that will require them to steal a valid cookie in the first place.

Comment: Not that you need the check of your variable against true in your test case, but when comparing booleans you're better off using the identical comparison. $test === true. Strive for being strict whenever possible.

Comment: @MetalFrog I know, but if it wasn't authentication (just benchmark in this case) I would use == as I can also supply "true" or 1 or "1"

Comment: If it was for a benchmark, wouldn't you want the most optimized version of the code?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No. The data in the $_SESSION variable is stored on the server, inaccessible from the user.

A session is coupled to a user through a cookie. A cookie with a identifier (i.e. a long random string) is sent to the user to identify the user and link him to his session. If somebody else gains access to this cookie, he can use that same code to pretent he is the user, and that way he can get in without the password.

Comment: the question was `Can a user get in without the super secure password?` and the answer is YES.

Comment: @PoelincaDorin - I think that anyone with a little bit salt in their head can see what's the problem and what's the proper answer. Yours isn't. This one is.

Answer (score 3):

Session could be modified in different occasions.. See this -> [Session Poisoning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_poisoning)

Comment: +50! surprised no vote up.. any updated information? Can you log QA answer?

Answer (score 2):

The session can only be modified from the PHP code, it's unlike `$_POST, $_GET, $_COOKIE` etc

As an aside I think you can use `empty()` to simplify your conditional:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!empty($_SESSION['authenticated']) {
    echo "Super secret stuff!";
}
?>
```